# Softon\Indipay is not instantiable while building

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, service-provider

I received this message when i try to instantiate `Soften\Indipay` on Laravel 5.4*
[github](https://github.com/softon/indipay)

> Target [Softon\Indipay\Gateways\PaymentGatewayInterface] is not instantiable while building [\Softon\Indipay\Indipay].

i registered it in the `app/config.php` but it doesn't work, how can i fix it ?

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    Softon\Indipay\IndipayServiceProvider::class,
    ....
];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Laravel `vendor\softon\indipay\src\IndipayServiceProvider.php`
modify the `register` function so that there are no leading slashes in the bindings.

```
$this->app->bind('indipay', '\Softon\Indipay\Indipay');
$this->app->bind('\Softon\Indipay\Gateways\PaymentGatewayInterface','\Softon\Indipay\Gateways\\'.$gateway.'Gateway');
```

should now look like

```
$this->app->bind('indipay', 'Softon\Indipay\Indipay');
$this->app->bind('Softon\Indipay\Gateways\PaymentGatewayInterface','Softon\Indipay\Gateways\\'.$gateway.'Gateway');
```

Also, don't forget to add the Indipay alias as

```
'Indipay' => 'Softon\Indipay\Facades\Indipay',
```

in your `config/app.php`